# How can I get eigenvalues and eigenvectors fast and accurate?

Tags: c++, matlab, linear-algebra, eigenvector, eigenvalue

I need to compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a big matrix (about 1000*1000 or even more). Matlab works very fast but it does not guaranty accuracy. I need this to be pretty accurate (about 1e-06 error is ok) and within a reasonable time (an hour or two is ok).

My matrix is symmetric and pretty sparse. The exact values are: ones on the diagonal, and on the diagonal below the main diagonal, and on the diagonal above it. Example:

[image: Example Matrix]

How can I do this? C++ is the most convenient to me.

Comment: This isn't a programming question so much as a math question. Take a look at: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/131527/eigenvalues-of-symmetric-tridiagonal-matrices

Comment: look into armadillo or eigen and use which best suits your needs

Comment: eigen is too slow (or maybe it has configuration options which I'm not aware of?). And it is a programming question because I'm not trying to write it on my own, I want to use something ready.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your system is [tridiagonal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix) and a (symmetric) [Toeplitz matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix). I'd guess that eigen and Matlab's `eig` have special cases to handle such matrices. There is a [closed-form solution for the eigenvalues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Eigenvalues) in this case ([reference (PDF)](http://rendiconti.dmi.units.it/volumi/20/09.pdf)). In Matlab for your matrix this is simply:

```
n = size(A,1);
k = (1:n).';
v = 1-2*cos(pi*k./(n+1));
```

This can be further optimized by noting that the eigenvalues are centered about `1` and thus only half of them need to be computed:

```
n = size(A,1);
if mod(n,2) == 0
    k = (1:n/2).';
    u = 2*cos(pi*k./(n+1));
    v = 1+[u;-u];
else
    k = (1:(n-1)/2).';
    u = 2*cos(pi*k./(n+1));
    v = 1+[u;0;-u];
end
```

I'm not sure how you're going to get more fast and accurate than that (other than performing a refinement step using the eigenvectors and optimization) with simple code. The above should be able to translated to C++ very easily (or use Matlab's [`codgen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ref/codegen.html) to generate C/C++ code that uses this or `eig`). However, your matrix is still ill-conditioned. Just remember that estimates of accuracy are worst case.

Comment: @horchler Nice analytical answer, +1. However, shouldn't there be a plus sign instead of a minus sign in the expression `v = 1-2*cos(pi*k./(n+1))`? (according to the article)

Comment: @EitanT: The PDF article and Wikipedia use different signs. I'm guessing it's convention as it just changes the order of the eigenvalues (`cos` is an even function), which only matters if the eigenvectors are needed.

Comment: Wow that's really great! I wonder why eigen does not do that (I assume so because it's too slow). The PDF has analytical formula for the eigenvectors either.

Comment: @EllaShar Although I hold absolutely no hard feelings for unaccepting my answer, I really don't see a practical difference between `eig(A)` and an explicit computation. While `eig(A)` is not as lightning fast (but still rather fast), it manages to produce the same results (and probably uses the same optimizations), and it *is* the more comprehensible way to do that. Perhaps I'm missing something here, but why resort to re-implementing this when you have it already done for you by a built-in function?

Comment: @EllaShar: I don't know anything about eigen, but the slowness could be related to it not having been compiled against the fastest math and linear algebra libraries, improper memory allocation, or maybe you're doing something wrong (you'd have to ask another question).

Comment: I don't think that's the reason. eigen does not need other math or linear algebra libraries, and memory should not influence that much (and I used it simply as in the examples of eigen). And I don't think I'm doing something wrong (but well, you can never know..).

Answer (score 5):

> **MATLAB does not guarrantee accuracy**

I find this claim unreasonable. On what grounds do you say that you can find a (significantly) more accurate implementation than MATLAB's highly refined computational algorithms?

AND... using MATLAB's [`eig`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html), the following is computed in less than half a second:

```
%// Generate the input matrix
X = ones(1000);
A = triu(X, -1) + tril(X, 1) - X;

%// Compute eigenvalues
v = eig(A);
```

It's fast alright!

> **I need this to be pretty accurate (about 1e-06 error is OK)**

Remember that solving eigenvalues accurately is related to finding the roots of the characteristic polynomial. This specific 1000x1000 matrix is *very* [ill-conditioned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ill-conditioned_matrix):

```
>> cond(A)

ans =
    1.6551e+003
```

[A general rule of thumb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) is that for a condition number of 10<sup>*k*</sup>, you may lose up to *k* digits of accuracy (on top of what would be lost to the numerical method due to loss of precision from arithmetic method).

So in your case, I'd expect the results to be accurate up to an approximate error of 10<sup>-3</sup>.

Comment: How does this answer the question? The OP wants to calculate eigenvalues in C++, you showed him that MATLAB is accurate.

Comment: @TylerJandreau The question is about computing eigenvalues accurately, and I infer that had MATLAB been accurate enough, it would suffice. It appears to be impossible to compute eigenvalues numerically for this type of matrix with the requested accuracy, so there's no reason not to be satisfied with MATLAB's answer. Why did you downvote my answer?

Comment: Thanks! But why does [V,D]=eig(A) and d=eig(A) give different eigenvalues as an answer and which should I use? Also, I think that the loss of precision to the numerical method can be big, can I set that? Matlab does not say anywhere how accurate the answer will be so I can't really trust it..

Comment: @EllaShar As mentioned in the answer, you can estimate the accuracy using the [condition number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number). I doubt that you can find a numerical algorithm noticeably better than MATLAB's. The most accurate method would probably be solving this analytically, but it's not always feasible.

Comment: @EllaShar regarding the outputs of `eig(A)`, [MATLAB's documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html) states that specifying one output gives you a *vector* of eigenvalues, while specifying two yields a diagonal *matrix* of eigenvalues and a matrix of eigenvectors. If you do `diag(D)` after `[V, D] = eig(A)`, you'll get the same result as `d = eig(A)`.

Comment: The thing is I did not get exactly the same result (and yes I tried sorting the vectors). Why is that and which one is more accurate?
Also, condition number does not guaranty anything about the numerical rounding, so I have no upper limit on the error.

Comment: @EllaShar what do you mean about "not get exactly the same result"? Regarding the numerical rounding, it's negligible when compared to the algorithmic accuracy of computing the eigenvalues (again, as mentioned, I expect it to be around 1e-3 in your case).

Comment: I mean that sort(diag(D)) does not equal sort(d). You can check it. If you are sure that the error will be around 1e-3 and it can't be much better anyway, then your answer is indeed good. Thanks a Lot!

Comment: @EllaShar Well, I checked that `mean(abs(d - diag(D)))` is around 1e-16, and so is their sorted counterparts, which means that they can be considered equivalent. Hope it helped!

Comment: Helped a lot! Do you know what's the reason for this difference?

Comment: @EllaShar The 1e-16? It's negligible, why waste your time dwelling on it? :)

Comment: Well I was just curious :)

Comment: @EllaShar Well, for what it's worth, I share your opinion that both results should be completely identical, and it's beyond my comprehension why it is not so (assuming they are obtained following the exact same algorithm). Then again, MATLAB's implementation might include a mathematical manipulation for one of the forms, that in turn introduces roundoff errors. However, as these minute differenes are so insignificant, you can treat both results as identical for all practical purposes.

Answer (score 4):

If you're not opposed to using a third party library, I've had great success using the [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) linear algebra libraries.

For the example below, `arma` is the namespace they like to use, `vec` is a vector, `mat` is a matrix.

```
arma::vec getEigenValues(arma::mat M) {
    return arma::eig_sym(M);
}
```

You can also serialize the data directly into `MATLAB` and vice versa.

Comment: Can you try running this for me? I tried using eigen and it was too slow. Thanks!

Comment: It would be faster to use arma::eig_sym() directly instead of wrapping in into a function.  Simply use `vec v = eig_sym(M);`.  Armadillo also has [more forms of the eig_sym()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#eig_sym) function, eg. using the "divide & conquer" algorithm, which is much faster for large matrices.

Comment: Thanks but I do not want to download armadillo for nothing, is it supposed to be faster than the eigen library? It will be best if you can run it and check. What are the cons of the 'dc' algorithm, how inaccurate will it be? And is there something similar in eigen (which I already have)? Thanks again!